# Java file instance without file extension

Tags: java, file, directory

I'm trying to get a File instance without knowing the file extension. I tried this based on another solution:

```
String extension = null;
String[] myFiles = dir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName) {
        if(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")==-1) return false;
        if((fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("."))).equals(storageId))
            extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("."), fileName.length());
    }
});
```

However it doesn't work (I can't affect the 'extension variable), how would I go around this to be able to grab the extension of the file?

Thank you very much

Comment: Return true in the second `if` in the `accept` method. Then loop through the returned `String[]` to get the extension of each file name.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into the problem that method of an anonymous inner class cannot modify a local variable in the classes enclosing scope.  The Java language doesn't allow it.  You can only refer to a local variable that is `final`.  (In Java 8, it doesn't have to be *declared* as final.  It just needs to be effectively final at the point where the anonymous class gets instantiated.)

There are a number of ways to work around this,  For example:

```
// #1
final String[] extension = new String[1];
String[] myFiles = dir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName) {
        ...
        extension[0] = ...
    }
});


// #2
final MyCustomStringHolder extension = ...
String[] myFiles = dir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName) {
        ...
        extension.setValue(...);
    }
});

// #3
private String extension = null;
public void method() {
    String[] myFiles = dir.list(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName) {
            ...
            extension = ...
        }
    });
```